# An error while trying to get AOV results of repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis, anova

My data is in long format. I am looking for the effect of time on score.
tried the following code:

```
res.aov <- aov(score~time+Error(ID/time), data=dat)
```

It displays the following error:

```
Warning message:
In aov(score ~ time + Error(ID/time), data = dat) :
  Error() model is singular
```

And I get the following results:

```
> summary(res.aov)

Error: ID
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
time       1   36.9   36.91   2.664  0.112
Residuals 32  443.4   13.85               

Error: ID:time
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
time       1   0.02  0.0168    0.01  0.919
Residuals 32  51.51  1.6096               

Error: Within
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 110  79.43  0.7221               
>
```

Why I can't see the p value of the within table? and How to deal with this error?

Answer (score 0):

You run into that error because one of your variable has only one entry per level, meaning there's no way to estimate its effects, for example:

```
dat =  data.frame(
ID = factor(letters[1:20]),
time=rep(1:5,4),
score=rnorm(20))

table(dat$ID)

a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 

res.aov <- aov(score~time+Error(ID/time), data=dat)
Warning message:
In aov(score ~ time + Error(ID/time), data = dat) :
  Error() model is singular
```

You need to be sure of the design, and run the correct model. If you have 20 data points that are unrelated, i.e 20 individuals, different time different scores, what you need is:

```
aov(score~time,data=dat)
```

If what you have is a repeated measure, i.e individuals tested for the same score at different time points, your data will look like this:

```
dat =  data.frame(
    ID = factor(rep(letters[1:4],each=5)),
    time=factor(rep(1:5,4)),
    score=rnorm(20))

table(dat$ID,dat$time)
   
    1 2 3 4 5
  a 1 1 1 1 1
  b 1 1 1 1 1
  c 1 1 1 1 1
  d 1 1 1 1 1

summary(aov(score~time+Error(ID/time),data=dat))

Error: ID
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  3  2.182  0.7272               

Error: ID:time
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
time       4  3.161  0.7903   0.654  0.635
Residuals 12 14.492  1.2077
```

Also note that in the above example for repeated measures, time has to be a factor and not continuous